# отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий этим операндам

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

> бинарный "=": не найден оператор, принимающий правый операнд типа "System::Object ^" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)

Ругается на вот эту строку:

```
s = listBox1->Items[i];
```

В знаке `=`

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1->Items->Count; i++) {
            string s;
            int a, b;
            s = listBox1->Items[i];
            a = stoi(s.substr(0, s.find('/')));
            b = stoi(s.erase(0, s.find('/') + 1));
            label1->Text += a/b;
        }
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: `System::Object ^` ... а стало быть это [tag:C++-cli].

Comment: Да, но мне нужно подогнать код в win forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала нужно элемент списка превратить в строку. Для этого подойдёт метод `ToString()`:

```
auto ms = listBox1->Items[i]->ToString();
```

Но так как в WinForms используются управляемые типы, тип `ms` будет `System::String^`, а не `std::string`, то потребуется еще [преобразование](https://stackoverflow.com/q/946813/3240681):

```
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
...
s = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(ms);
```

Но если есть возможность, лучше, конечно, оставаться в пределах единственной иерархии типов.

Comment: но тогда не будут работать последующие функции. Если добавить ToString(), то подчеркивает listBox1 и пишет что выражение должно иметь тип класса.

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин со `->` попробуйте вместо точки. Я немного на `C#` переключился :)

Comment: Бывает)
 Тогда выдает такую ошибку: отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий этим операндам.

Comment: @alexolut, но `System::String^` - это не `std::string`...

Comment: @Qwertiy теперь учёл этот момент

Comment: Ага, вижу - наверное, должно работать :)

Comment: А что значит var ms ? ms - это имя переменной,а var?

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин это я снова на c# съехал, надо на `auto` заменить. [Должно работать](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2007976/3240681).

Comment: В коде ошибок не показывает, теперь ругается на ошибки в библиотеке https://ibb.co/mgKkUo

Comment: @ВасилийПупкин заголовочный файл добавьте в код `#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>`

Comment: Работает) Благодарю!

Answer (score 1):

Так как это C++/CLI, то используйте типы и методы .NET.

```
String^ s = listBox1->Items[i]->ToString();
array<String^>^ splitted = s->Split('/');
int a = Int32::Parse(splitted[0]);
int b = Int32::Parse(splitted[1]);
label1->Text += (a/b).ToString();
```

Писал в браузере, возможны ошибки.

Comment: К сожалению, выдает ряд ошибок. Вот их список: https://ibb.co/febkeo